# Bootstrap, hamburger icon does not respond in a navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have written a basic *navbar* in boostrap and it does not pop up when clicked in the mobile view. I don't know weather its a error in the code or I have not included any script but I have included both *jQuery* at the top of the script and *bootstrap.js* at the bottom.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Navbars</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
            </div>


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>  
        </div>


    </nav>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to also include bootstrap.js and make the necessary `ID` change as indicated in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nav bar should have an `id="my-navbar"`

```
<div id="my-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse"></div>
```

Your button should have a `data-target="#my-navbar"`

```
<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my-navbar" >
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"` to you menu, just add and it work fine

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```